# Can SQLAlchemy return a grouped_by query as a dictionary?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a `Trace` model and I wonder if I can do better than that:

```
traces = Trace.query.filter(some_filtering).all()
return {
        student_id: [trace for trace in traces if trace.student_id == student_id]
        for student_id in student_ids
    }
```

Can SQLAlchemy return a dictionary directly using the `grouped_by` variable as keys of the dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not pure SQLAlchemy but combined with `itertools.groupby`:

```
qry = Trace.query.order_by(Trace.student_id)
grouped = {k: list(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(qry, lambda t: t.student_id)}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
traces = Trace.query.grouped_by(Trace.id).filter(some_filtering).all()
traces_dict_list=[]
for trace_row in traces:
    traces_dict_list.append(trace_row .__dict__)
```